# Overwrite original geometry UVMap with Geometry Nodes uv_map

Tags: uv, shaders, geometry-nodes, shader-nodes

Is there a way of overwriting the UVMap of the object, the one used by the Texture Coordinate node, with the generated uv_map that geometry nodes produce with the primitives? I want my procedural geo node objects to have usable UV's without having to change my textures to use the generated uv_map attribute.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can also transfer the "uv_map" from one object to another as described here and write it into the attribute "UVMap": https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/271403/145249

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a [Known Issue](https://developer.blender.org/T85962) for now. Hopefully it will be resolved in future implementations.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this script to convert UVMap attributes to a regular UVMap. Just copy it into the text editor and execute. Tested in Blender 3.2.2.

**Important before doing it:**

1. Your UVMap attribute has to be named `UVMap`.
2. You need to apply the geometry nodes modifier first.
3. You need to select your UVMap attribute inside the Attributes tab in the data properties of your geometry nodes object.

   ```
   import bpy
    a = bpy.context.object.data.attributes
    a.active = a['UVMap']
    bpy.ops.geometry.attribute_convert(mode='UV_MAP', domain='CORNER', data_type='FLOAT2')
   ```

The original hint is by Andrey-730 and can be found here: https://devtalk.blender.org/t/attribute-transfer-to-uv-layer/23016/7