# How to replicate the same material in every instance after realize instances node? [SOLVED]

Tags: materials, geometry-nodes, instances

I have one of those problems where a solution seems to be right in front of you, but you can't reach it.

I have a grid o x number of instances, and I want my material to be replicated in these instances like so:

[image: realize instances OFF]

The problem is that I need to use Realize Instances for other purposes, but once I use it, the material is applied to the mesh as a whole:

[image]

So how do I keep Realize on and still get the effect of the first pic?

---

[EDIT]
The instances are simple grids (planes) created inside geo nodes.

The original object is the default cube, although I'm not using the original mesh.

The very first pic shows the result of not using or muting Realise Instance

[image]

### [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve it as follows *(Blender 3.1+)*:

[image]

Since the grid you created in *Geometry Nodes* already has a *UV-Map*, you can use it directly.

However, the *UV-Map* generated here has the name "uv_map", and not "UVMap", as it would be the case for example with a mesh created in the conventional way.

So that your shader can use this map, you use the node `Attribute` there and specify the identifier "uv_map".

---

In this example, however, I use a default cube as a base. And this has by default already a *UV-Map* with the name "UVMap".

If you create more geometry in *Geometry Nodes*, you can also use this value and store your *UV-Map* there.

You could solve this as follows *(Blender 3.2)*:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Jeez, this is confusing. (Not you, _it_)

Comment: @RobinBetts Really strange, isn't it? Do you have any idea why this is so and not also the identifier "UVMap" is used? Maybe so that nothing gets in each other's way, or what? ...but I can be quite confusing too ...sometimes :D

Comment: Could be an intermediate step on the way to Everything Nodes? IMO it would eventually make sense for the UV Map to just a field attribute like any other, not requiring a separate interface? Don't know... import/export.. unwrapping...